# Error in Google Apps Script: mime type error when using getPlainText

Tags: google-apps-script

When I tried to use the getPlainBody() method of GmailMessage class. When I execute the following code, the error message "**Invalid MIME type**" show up. Can anyone help me to verify what's wrong in my code?

```
function processLabel(labelName) {
  var targetLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelName);
  var targetThreads = targetLabel.getThreads();
  return targetThreads;
};

function getEmailPlainText() {
  var targetThreads = processLabel('@today');
  var threadsCount = targetThreads.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++) {
    var targetThread = targetThreads[i];
    var messageCount = targetThread.getMessageCount();
    var subject = targetThread.getFirstMessageSubject();
    var lastMessage = targetThread.getMessages()[messageCount-1];
    var lastMessageContent = lastMessageContent = lastMessage.getPlainBody();
};
```

Comment: I verified this code and tested it. Code run without any error and it was able to get the latest message content.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug when the message has certain type of attachments.

[Check here and vote it up](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3428)

Comment: If you want to make your answer useful, give a minimal description of what is after the link...